# Binding button to label widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button, tkinter-label

Trying to call `hii` function in python tkinter, but nothing happens.

My Code:-

```py
def hii():
    print("hii")


m_root = Tk()
m_frame = Frame(m_root)
m_display = Label(m_frame)

label = Label(m_root,text="hii") #set your text
label.bind("<Enter>",hii)
label.pack()

m_display.pack()
m_frame.pack()
m_display.update()

m_root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you sure _nothing_ happens? You should be getting an error when your mouse hovers over the label.

Comment: @Matiiss Don't confuse `"<Enter>"` with `"<Return>"`. BryanOakley is correct in saying that an error should be raised

Comment: Ohh yes @BryanOakley , when I move mouse to text, i have message on console: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: hi() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: @Deoj Do you want the event to be triggered when you press the enter key on your keyboard or when the mouse cursor `Enter`s the widget?

Comment: @Deoj that is because `.bind()` passes another argument `event` so it should be handled either like this: `.bind("Event", lambda e: func())` or `def func(event):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line should be: `def hii(event):` and it works fine.
The function should expect an event as an argument.